# Variable assignment creating a file in current directory, not assigning variable

Tags: bash, io-redirection, comparison-operators

I'm creating a custom script to run backups using Clonezilla. The script is working as expected (so far) but I'm having a little trouble with the variable assignment.

The variable assignment line (maxBackups=4) creates a file called '4' in the current directory and the if test doesn't work properly.

(the way I understand it, the link to the parent directory counts as a directory with this directory counting method.)

What am I doing wrong? I know it is something simple...

Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash

# Automated usb backup script for Clonezilla
# by DRC


# Begin script

# Store date and time for use in folder name
# to a variable called folderName


folderName=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M")

# mount second partition of USB media for storing
# saved image

mount /dev/sdb2 /home/partimag/ 


# Determine if there are more than 3 directories
# and terminate the script if there are

cd /home/partimag
maxBackups=4
numberOfBackups=$(find -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l)

if [ $numberOfBackups > $maxBackups ]; then
echo "The maximum number of backups has been reached."
echo "Plese burn the backups to DVD and remove them"
echo "from the USB key."
echo "Press ENTER to continue and select 'Poweroff'"
echo "from the next menu."

# Wait for the user to press the enter key

read

# If there are three or less backups, a new backup will be made

else
/usr/sbin/ocs-sr -q2 -c -j2 -a -z0 -i 2000 -sc -p true savedisk $folderName sda

fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`maxBackups=4` is not creating a file named `4` in your directory. What is creating that file is the `if [ $numberOfBackups > $maxBackups ]` bit. `>` is redirection to an output file, since `[` is a command, not a keyword. You could try one of these instead:

```
if [ $numberOfBackups -gt $maxBackups ]     # -gt is test's version of greater than

if [[ $numberOfBackups > $maxBackups ]]     # double brackets are keywords, not commands

if (( numberOfBackups > maxBackups ))       # arithmetic context doesn't even require $
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked like a charm! Tried to vote you up but don't have enough rep...